# How to set a text content of a specific column as a variable using Batch or PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

For example, I have a file/file output with the following content:

2022-10-16 14:33 1,860,477 Mausi-~1.JPG Mausi-wife.JPG

There are spaces between these five blocks in between, i.e. between date and time and number and file name and another file name.

I would now like to set only the fourth column of this as a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: In a batch file: ```@For /F "Tokens=4" %%G In ("string") Do @Set "var=%%G"```, or maybe ```@For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=4" %%G In ("filecontent") Do @Set "var=%%G"```.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please use the search feature on top of this page! What you want has already been asked thousands of times…

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on spaces, update the desired value in the resulting array, and then stitch back together with `-join`:

```
$row = '2022-10-16 14:33 1,860,477 Mausi-~1.JPG Mausi-wife.JPG'

# split into individual field values
$fields = $row.Split(' ')

# update/overwrite the 4th item in the resulting string array
$fields[3] = "New value"

# stitch row back together with `-join`
$row = $fields -join ' '
```

Comment: I interpreted the question differently than you.  I understand BatchBoyii to want to obtain the current value in the fourth column,  and transfer that value to a variable.